# Referring to other Block variables within a Block statement?

Tags: dataset

In

```
Block[{ ds = Dataset[{
     <|"task" -> "task4", "parents" -> "parent1", 
      "start" -> "2019-05-14 17:10", "end" -> "2019-05-14 17:15", 
      "utility" -> "0.9"|>}
    ],
  hrAssociation = 
   KeySort[Merge[
     Rule @@@ 
       Flatten[GroupBy[
           ds[All, <|"d" -> (DateObject /@ {#"start", #"end"})|> &], 
           First -> Last, 
           Map[{CurrentDate[#[[1]], "Day"], 
              DateDifference[#[[1]], #[[2]], "Hour"]} &]] // Normal // 
         Values, 1] // Sort, Total]]},
 hrAssociation
 ]
```

I get

> [image]

and I think it's because I'm referring to the first dataset variables (`ds`) deep within the second variable (`hrAssociation`). How to fix?

I have tried replacing `Block` with `With` and `Module` and the problem persists.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
Module[{ds,hrAssociatio}
    ,
     ds = Dataset[{
         <|"task" -> "task4", "parents" -> "parent1", 
          "start" -> "2019-05-14 17:10", "end" -> "2019-05-14 17:15", 
          "utility" -> "0.9"|>}
        ]
    ;  hrAssociation = 
       KeySort[Merge[
         Rule @@@ 
           Flatten[GroupBy[
               ds[All, <|"d" -> (DateObject /@ {#"start", #"end"})|> &], 
               First -> Last, 
               Map[{CurrentDate[#[[1]], "Day"], 
                  DateDifference[#[[1]], #[[2]], "Hour"]} &]] // Normal // 
             Values, 1] // Sort, Total]
        ]
    ; hrAssociation
    ]
```

Comment: I see that this works, but why is my code wrong? Is it a bug in Mathematica or a conceptual error I'm making?

Comment: It's a conceptual error. Assignments happen first, before the scoping occurs. The scoped arguments are only in the second block.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Rolf's answer, if you *need* this in the body of the declaration you can use `:=`

```
Block[{ds = 
   Dataset[{<|"task" -> "task4", "parents" -> "parent1", 
      "start" -> "2019-05-14 17:10", "end" -> "2019-05-14 17:15", 
      "utility" -> "0.9"|>}
    ],
  hrAssociation :=
   KeySort[
    Merge[
     Rule @@@
       Flatten[
        GroupBy[
           ds[All, <|"d" -> (DateObject /@ {#"start", #"end"})|> &], 
           First -> Last, 
           Map[{CurrentDate[#[[1]], "Day"], 
              DateDifference[#[[1]], #[[2]], "Hour"]} &
            ]
           ] // Normal // Values, 1] // Sort,
     Total
     ]
    ]
  },
 hrAssociation
 ]
```